# .bindPopup is not a function-leaflet

Tags: popup, leaflet

I am using leaflet maps.here am trying to show popup based on id.

```
$scope.LocationCnfgCallBack = function(response) {
        var locationCnfg = response.data.record;

        $.each(locationCnfg.features,function(i,value){
            var location=value.id
            //location.bindLable('here is yur popup').addTo(map).openPopup();
            location.bindPopup('here is yur popup')
        })
        location.on('mouseover',
                function(e) {
                    this.openPopup();
                });
        location.on('mouseout',
                function(e) {
                    this.closePopup();
                });
    }
```

`var location` returns ids like `room`,`floor`,`building` .
when I hover on each id I need to show popup but am getting 2 errors here.they are

-> location.bindPopup is not a function

-> location.on is not a function

what I did wrong?why popup is not displaying?

Comment: What kind of data is in response.data.record?

Comment: Hey, 2 things that I can see 1.Popup can be binded to map/layergroup/layer 2. The scope of your location var does not fit the mouseover/mouseout functions.